# count numbers of tag_name in a webpage (python, selenium)

Tags: python, selenium, xpath, html

Hi have the following code:

```
for each in driver.find_elements_by_xpath(".//*[@id='ip_market" + market + "']/table/tbody")
    cell = each.find_elements_by_tag_name('td')[0]
    cell2 = each.find_elements_by_tag_name('td')[1]
    cell3 = each.find_elements_by_tag_name('td')[2]
```

My problem is that I don't know exactly how many `td`s there are inside every `each` (sometimes 3, sometimes 15 etc etc...).

Is there a possibility to check the numbers of `td`s inside the `for each` in order to make dynamic `find_elements_by_tag_name('td')`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just don't get them by index, use:

```
cells = each.find_elements_by_tag_name('td')
```

then `cells` would be a *list of elements* which you can call `len()` on:

```
print(len(cells))
```

Or slice:

```
cells[:3]  # gives first 3 elements
cell1, cell2, cell3 = cells[:3]  # unpacking into separate variables
```

Or, you can get the text of every cell:

```
[cell.text for cell in cells]
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer!!! :) My problem is that i need the index in order to insert the data correctly in my sql database, otherwise i don't know how to insert them... Sorry but i'm new in python and sql... But if you have a better solution i'm happy to hear it? :D

Comment: @Lord sorry, but is unclear what are you trying to do. Could you may be add more code you have so far and add some details about your end goal? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

`find_elements_by_tag_name` returns a list. Use `len()` on that list to get the number of elements by that tag name. Also, rather than saying `for each` I'd gently suggest using more descriptive assignments.

```
table = driver.find_element_by_xpath(".//*[@id='ip_market" + market + "']/table/tbody")
table_rows = table.find_elements_by_tag_name("tr")
for row in table_rows:
    row_cells = row.find_elements_by_tag_name("td")
    num_of_cells = len(row_cells)
```

Answer (score 0):

From reading your comments, it looks like this is what you are trying to do...

```
for each in driver.find_elements_by_xpath(".//*[@id='ip_market" + market + "']/table/tbody")
    for i in range(0,len(each.find_elements_by_tag_name('td'))
        // you can now use i as an index into the loop through the TDs
        print "do something interesting with i: " + i
```